# Python to pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

What will be the pyspark code for the below code .

```py
df["Brought through walmart"] = df["email domain"].apply(
    lambda x: 1
    if x == "walmart.com" and "WALMART.COM" and "walmartemail.com" and "walmarmt.co.uk"
    else 0
)
```

Getting error:   TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

Comment: do you realise that this condition `if x == "walmart.com" and "WALMART.COM" and "walmartemail.com" and "walmarmt.co.uk"` only checks for `x == "walmart.com"` ?  the rest of the strings are always true conditions ... If you want to check for x is one of the string, you should use `in` : `x in ("A", "B", ...)`

Comment: how can i add these column or another column say "brought through target" to dataframe df ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `df` is your dataframe, and the condition you want to check is `x in ("walmart.com", "WALMART.COM", "walmartemail.com", "walmarmt.co.uk")` - the one you wrote in your question is absurd, you should check its results :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn(
    "Brought through walmart",
    F.when(
        F.col("email domain").isin(
            "walmart.com", "WALMART.COM", "walmartemail.com", "walmarmt.co.uk"
        ),
        1,
    ).otherwise(0),
)
```

Comment: how can i add these column or another column say "brought through target"  to dataframe df

Comment: @Thedatageek did you try my code ? what is it that you do not understand ? cause that is what my code is doing : adding the column to the dataframe. That's literaly in the name : `df.withColumn`. Here is the link to the [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn) if you need more informations.